# Is it possible to override the Form's CreateParams method/function from a C# component?

Tags: c#, winforms, dropshadow, uicomponents, createparams

I am trying to apply a dropshadow for the bordeless winform from a component by overriding its CreateParams function but I'm getting an exception "no suitable method found to override" within the component.

How best can I apply a borderless WinForm's dropshadow from a component or is it possible to do so?

I can apply a dropshadow within the form itself but creating a component will make it easy to reuse the code.

I am trying to achieve this in winform using c#.

Comment: By the time the component is created the `Form` object already exists (CreateParams has been called).  You could do this as a `Form` that you inherit your others forms from.   `public class MySuperSpecialForm : DropshadowForm {...}`

Comment: Can the dropshadow effect be set with Win32 Window Styles (e.g. `SetWindowLong()`)?

Comment: You can't "hook" a protected virtual method.  Only alternative is to create a dedicated Form-derived class so it can co-operate in its CreateParams override, but then you don't really need that component anymore.

Comment: Okay. I thought I was missing something. I appreciate all your clarifications.

Comment: @Sam: I will try that

Comment: @Hans: I appreciate your clarification. I will try your approach as well. Better now that I know why I'm getting the error. Thank you.

Comment: @Sam: I just tried your advice. It worked. Creating a Form and then inheriting all my other winforms from it. I really appreciate your helpful approach.

Comment: @Hans: I created a Form-derived class and it worked. Thank you all for saving me time by offering the best approach.